# Term for a group of doctors, nurses who go to help the victims after natural disasters?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for a group of doctors, nurses who go to help the victims after a natural disaster?

Something like *first-aid kit* that we use to help an injured person on the spot.

I'm thinking of *emergency first-aid group* but I don't think that's the right phrase.

Comment: [Regional Disaster Response Teams (RDRT) or Regional Intervention Teams (RIT)](http://www.ifrc.org/en/what-we-do/disaster-management/responding/disaster-response-system/dr-tools-and-systems/regional-disaster-response-teams/) have their own acronyms. But a native speaker wouldn't necessarily think of such terms - the bureaucratic process by which such things are named doesn't usually have much to do with "natural use of English". Personally, I've nothing against ***crash teams***, even though they're more often associated with saving *one* person with cardiac problems.

Comment: Emergency rescue team, [Incident/Emergency response team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incident_response_team)?

Comment: An umbrella acronym for private aid organizations and their people on the ground is **NGO**. They're not limited to medical personnel, however.

Comment: Thank you guys, with these hints I guess I got my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention "first aid", I suggest "first responders".

Wikipedia: [First responder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_responder)

> A first responder is an employee of an emergency service who is likely to be among the first people to arrive at and assist at the scene of an emergency, such as an accident, natural disaster, or terrorist attack. First responders typically include police officers, firefighters, paramedics, and emergency medical technicians.

A first responder (one of them) is usually going to be part of a group, these guys normally work in teams.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for answering. Please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you'll ask some questions of your own. (We usually use `backtick` formatting for code; look at other answers for a better way to set off cited text.)